# dealing with rvalue ref inside tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple

I want to pass and forward tuples which contain rvalue ref. But I am not able to access the tuple element and do forwarding in the correct way.

In the example I provide also a structure with named elements instead of a `std::tuple` which works well.

So I simply can't find the answer myself how to write that line:

```
return Y{ std::forward<decltype(std::get<0>(t))>( std::get<0>( t ) ) };
```

so that I got the correct type forwarded.

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class X
{   
    private:
        int data;
    public:
        X( int _data ): data{_data}{}
};  


class Y
{   
    public:
        Y( const X&  ) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
        Y(       X&& ) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; } 
};  

struct Sm { X&& x; };
struct Sc {  X& x; };

template < typename AnyS >
Y func( const AnyS& s ) 
{   
    return Y{ std::forward<decltype(s.x)>(s.x) };
}   

template < typename ... PARMS >
Y func( const std::tuple< PARMS... >& t ) 
{   
    return Y{ std::forward<decltype(std::get<0>(t))>( std::get<0>( t ) ) };
}

int main()
{
    Sm sm{ X{1} };
    Y ym = func( sm ); // should move, fine works
        
    X x{1};
    Sc sc{ x };
    Y yc = func( sc ); // should copy, fine works

    Y ytm = func( std::tuple< X& >{ x }); // should copy, works 
    Y ytc = func( std::tuple< X&& >{ X{1} }); // should move but copies! FAIL
}
```

I know that I can use forwarding reference for the tuple itself. That will work fine but is not possible inside my code as I intentionally need to have some data duplication inside it which will not work if I forward the tuple itself by rvalue reference. If I could use it, I simple can use [make_from_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::get` returns a reference to the object when dealing with a tuple. So even if it's a rvalue-ref the return type of `std::get` will be a lvalue-ref.

To get the type from the tuple, use `std::tuple_element` instead.

```
return Y{ std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<PARMS...>>>( std::get<0>( t ) ) };
```

**Edit:**
If I understand you comment correctly, you should be able to expand it by aliasing the tuple type.

```
template <typename ... PARMS, std::size_t... Is>
Y func(const std::tuple<PARMS...>& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using tt = std::tuple<PARMS...>;
    return (Y{ std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<Is, tt>>( std::get<Is>( t ) ) }, ...);
}

template < typename ... PARMS, int... Is >
Y func( const std::tuple< PARMS... >& t ) 
{
    return func(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(PARMS)>{});
}
```

Comment: Great! No I have an additional question, maybe I should open a new one... If the constant value given here (0) is a var "I" from an index sequence to forward all parameters from the tuple, I run into the wrong order of expansion as "I" is now present mutiple times... Is there a trick with some braces somewhere... still searching :-)

Comment: Maybe you can get away with `using tuple_type = std::tuple<PARMS...>;`. Then you should be able to expand the 2 `I`s together. Would be easier to answer if you showed some code example.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `func` copies the rvalues inside the tuple because they cannot be moved out since your tuple is const:

```
// -----v
Y func( const std::tuple< PARMS... >& t )
```

When calling get, it will return a reference to the member, and since it's a constant tuple, it will be a constant reference, which will be copied.

But, `std::get` also do some kind of forwarding. For example, if you send a `std::tuple<T>&` to `std::get`, it will return a `T&`. If you want forwarding, you will in your case have to move the tuple:

```
template<typename ... PARMS>
Y func(std::tuple<PARMS...> t) 
{   
    return Y{std::get<0>(std::move(t))};
}
```

Then, as a bonus, you don't need the forward since the forwarding is done by `std::get`.

Comment: My understanding is to *not* move the tuple but the element which is referenced from the tuple. What you suggest is the thing implemented in `make_from_tuple`. In my case, I can have the objects itself, r&l-value refs. So simply do a move on the tuple inside my "generic" function will not fit. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Klaus well, in `std::get<x>(t)` t is an lvalue. Just like accessing `obj.data` gives an l-value even if `obj` has been decaled an rvalue reference, `obj` and `obj.data` are gonna be lvalues. Same for tuple. `std::get<x>(t)` is gonna give you lvalues, and forwarding it will also result in lvalue, and copies.

Comment: If the tuple is const, even if you try to move it, it's always gonna be a copy.

Comment: That breaks my head! If the tuple is const but the "member" is a rvalue ref, why we need a copy instead a move. I did not want to move the tuple but the object which the member is referencing to. It sounds like that a object which rvalue ref is referencing to will be "part of the tuple" instead only having a reference (rvalue reference) to it.

Comment: You can't move an object out of a constant tuple, just as you can't move a const unique_ptr. Moving needs mutability. Also, if I continue with the struct analogy, `auto d = std::move(obj).data` it will move `data`, not `obj`. Remember that `std::move` is only a cast to rvalue and nothing else. But also, `auto d = std::move(obj.data)` is equivalent to the other one.

Comment: For example, `std::vector<int> const v1(15); auto v2 = std::move(v1)` will copy, since `v2` can't steal the guts of `v1`, and will fallback to copy.

Comment: Can't catch it! I don't want to move the vector nor the data from the struct. The struct should contain not the data, it should contain an rvalue reference! The data itself is NOT part of the struct. sizeof(obj)->4 and NOT containing the data. I am totally wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200729/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-klaus).

Comment: Sorry, cant go to chat as our firewall blocks it :-( Thanks for the invite... maybe I come some ours later... if you are still there.

Comment: tl;dr struct don't forward constness on reference so forwarding work. Tuple is stricter.